# Why can I not register System.Web in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

Running this command:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY 
[System.Web] from
'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\system.web.dll'
with permission_set = UNSAFE
```

Gives me this error:

> Msg 10300, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>
> Assembly 'System.Web' references assembly 'system.web, version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.', which is not present in the current database. SQL Server attempted to locate and automatically load the referenced assembly from the same location where referring assembly came from, but that operation has failed (reason: version, culture or public key mismatch). Please load the referenced assembly into the current database and retry your request.

... this sounds a little silly. It seems like SQL Server thinks that the System.Web assembly is referencing it's self. How can I fix this?

Comment: Using System.Web from SQLCLR procedures is the one sure way to freeze your SQL server. Use an external process.

Comment: We're using WCF (of which System.Web is a dependency), which works fine on our other dev machine.

Comment: What's your point in registering managed and system (non-custom) dll from unmanaged (and also non-custom) SQL Server?

Comment: Sorry vgv8, I do not understand your question.

Comment: @RemusRusanu, I know your comment's a little old now, but do you have any details on the deleterious effects of using *System.Web* in a CLR procedure? I was going to try it but now I'm going to look for alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out System.web.dll isn't supported for this. In fact, it turned out that loading DLLs into SQL Server like this (for CLR) was a bad idea on many levels (one of which was 64/32-bit support between deployments).

Comment: CREATE ASSEMBLY [system.web]
FROM 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\system.web.dll'    
WITH PERMISSION_SET = unsafe--EXTERNAL_ACCESS;

Answer (score 7):

Try with Framework64 assemblies (64 bit sql server 2008)

CREATE ASSEMBLY

[System.Web] from

'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\System.Web.dll'
with permission_set = UNSAFE

GO

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to install the .Net 2.0 framework on your database server.

Also, I wouldn't directly add a reference to System.Web.dll.  Your other custom CLR code should reference that.  (Or, if you don't have custom .Net code, you should create a custom .Net project to interface into the System.Web assembly.)

Comment: Nice memory!  I can't remember what my machine had installed from 11 months ago!

Comment: If other .NET CLR code references the *System.Web* assembly then it too has to be registered (created) in SQL Server.